# How to convert inkscape pdf_tex to pdf

Tags: graphics, pdftex, inkscape

I recently made all my figures for pdflatex by using Inkscape’s pdf_tex-feature, which makes the figure fonts become nice etc.

But, afterwards, it turned out that the journal compiler did not handle these correctly.. :( How to convert?

Comment: Use the `standalone` class and convert the images separately.

Comment: Ah, worked like a charm!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I solved it myself, and want to store it here for archival purposes should this happen to anyone else searching for the solution.

On mac (or linux) create this bash-script and run it with the filename (without extension), eg: *bash scriptfile imagefile* if the imagefiles are named *imagefile.pdf* and *imagefile.pdf_tex*. This will create a nice file called *imagefile_converted.pdf* which will work in any journal.

Here follows the content of *scriptfile* above:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat > $1_converted.tex << EOF
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
\def\svgwidth{8cm}
\input{changeme.pdf_tex}
\end{document}
EOF

sed -i -e "s/changeme/$1/g" $1_converted.tex
pdflatex $1_converted.tex
rm $1_converted.aux $1_converted.log $1_converted.tex $1_converted.tex-e $1_converted.tex
open $1_converted.pdf
```